# How to remove empty bbcode from string in the PHP?

Tags: php, regex, url, replace, bbcode

> I am write this because, I am update string with "bbcode" on the `database` and I can not use `contenteditable`... after the getting string on the database parsed bbCodes. bbCode add-ins do not work the way I want.

I am have a simple **BBCODE** parser.

```
//////////////////////////////
function bbc2html($content) {
  $search = array (
    '/(\[b\])(.*?)(\[\/b\])/',
    '/(\[i\])(.*?)(\[\/i\])/',
    '/(\[u\])(.*?)(\[\/u\])/',
    '/(\[ul\])(.*?)(\[\/ul\])/',
    '/(\[li\])(.*?)(\[\/li\])/',
    '/(\[url=)(.*?)(\])(.*?)(\[\/url\])/',
    '/(\[url\])(.*?)(\[\/url\])/'
  );

  $replace = array (
    '<strong>$2</strong>',
    '<em>$2</em>',
    '<u>$2</u>',
    '<ul>$2</ul>',
    '<li>$2</li>',
    '<a href="$2" target="_blank">$4</a>',
    '<a href="$2" target="_blank">$2</a>'
  );

  return preg_replace($search, $replace, $content);
}
//////////////////////////////
```

I was write a insert bbcode `"textarea"` javascript function. But my guests is oldman, and they by mistake multi click or do not perception how to work `"bbcode"` actions.

Most of the time my content strings have parent in parent bbcodes. Like this: `[b][b]Simple[/b][b][/b][/b]`

How can i replace a clean version: `[b][b]Simple[/b][b][/b][/b]` to `[b]Simple[/b]` ?

**e.g.** I want to clean this all odds,

```
[?][[/?]?]***[/?][/?] => wrong click => output = "[?]***[/?]"

[?][/?] => empty => output = ""

[?]**[/?] => small 3  => output = "**"

[url=]****[/url] => empty url => output = "****"

[url]****[/url] => is not url => output = "****"
```

Comment: Why write your own BBCode parser when [dozens already exist](https://packagist.org/?q=bbcode&p=0)?

Comment: or the built in one http://php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php

Comment: I feel very confused and I can not get out of it. So I wrote it myself..

Comment: If you will sure not cause problems like this, I will spend more time applying them [link](https://packagist.org/?q=bbcode&p=0)

Comment: `[b][b]Simple[/b][b][/b][/b] ` is an irregular patten, and thus cannot be solved with a regular expression.

Comment: @wp78de That's true using the traditional [regular language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) definition of regular expressions, but modern regular expression syntax allows recursion (in the `[b][b]Simple[/b][b][/b][/b]` example, [`\[b\][^[\]]*(?R)*[^[\]]*\[\/b\]`](https://regex101.com/r/3er9NM/1/) could work for a subset of cases).

Comment: @Graham I am aware of regex recursion. The problem here is that the OP does not only want to match a string that CONTAINS a valid hierarchical structure but simplify/modify it - and that would require some sort of counting/understanding of the parts of the nested parts. Maybe a good application for .NET's Balancing Groups.